# Lift a group action from a quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, modules, group-actions, p-groups

Let $p$ be a rational prime and $H$ be a finite cyclic group of prime order $l$ prime to $p$, i.e. $(l,p) = 1$. Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of $p$-power order.

If I can write an (abelian) group $\Delta$ as a direct product like
$$\Delta = G \times H$$
then $H$ acts trivially on $G$. Now I know that $G$ is a quotient group, say $G = G_1 / N$, via a normal subgroup $N$ of a finite abelian group $G_1$ of exponent $p$.

> What can I say about the action of $H$ on $G_1$?

I need to find the representations of the group $H$, that acts on (the $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space) $G_1$, but I don't know about the action.

**Background** The ultimative goal is described in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534312/link-between-representation-theory-and-galois-theory-trivial-representation-in). All of the above groups are in fact Galois groups of certain field extensions and I'm interested in the link between Galois theory and representation theory.

**Module formulation** Since $H$ acts trivially on the finite abelian $p$-group $G$, $G$ becomes a trivial $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}[H]$ module. My question is therefore analogous to: Does $H$ act trivially on a $\mathbb{F}_p[H]$-submodule of $G_1$? In other words: **Does the $\mathbb{F}_p[H]$-module $G_1$ contain a trivial $\mathbb{F}_p[H]$-submodule?** (I'm not sure about this since $G$ is just a quotient of $G_1$ by the normal subgroup $N$) Notice that $\mathbb{F}_p[H]$ is semisimple by Maschke's theorem.

Thank you :-)

Comment: Added a module formulation.

Comment: Why do you start out only saying $G$ has $p$-power order; why not state up front it has exponent $p$? What does $G\times H$ have to do with anything; why not just say $H$ acts on $G$ trivially? How are you justified in talking about "the" action of $H$ on $G_1$; in general won't there by numerous actions of $H$ on $G_1$ that stabilize $N$ and act trivially on $G_1/N$?